# encrypted password kafka ssl setup

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am wondering to encrypt the password for ssl setup of kafka cluster.

my current setup:

```
listeners=SSL://:9095, PLAINTEXT://:9094
ssl.keystore.location=keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=phoenix
ssl.truststore.location=keystore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

but I dont want to have a plain **password** , expecting the encrypted this password

Answer (score 0):

I don't think kafka provides any option for storing encrypted password. This [doc](http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/ssl.html#overview) specifically says `Since we are storing passwords in the broker config, it is important to restrict access via file system permissions.`

Comment: we have solved this problem as it was our security concern.
What we have done is that we have interferred the process of loading properties at kafka-core module.
Thanks

Comment: Joey, can you elaborate on what you implemented a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

> #### Updating Password Configs Dynamically
>
> Password config values that are dynamically updated are encrypted before storing in ZooKeeper. The broker config `password.encoder.secret` must be configured in `server.properties` to enable dynamic update of password configs. The secret may be different on different brokers.

Source: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs

Comment: @ShadowMitia: Despite the confusing wording, it’s not clear who it’s thanking. This is a different link and explanation from the existing answer. It seems to be a new answer to me.